# rapidjson: How can I split a Document object to a smaller Document object?

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I am working on a C++ project and I use `rapidjson` for JSON parsing. I have this JSON:

```
{
  "a": "valA",
  "b": {
    "ba": "valBA",
    "bb": "valBB",
    "bc": "valBC"
  },
  "c": "valC"
}
```

I parse the whole JSON and I get a `Document` object containing all values. What I want is to somehow process this `Document` object and extract only the `b` part. As if I was parsing this JSON:

```
{
  "b": {
    "ba": "valBA",
    "bb": "valBB",
    "bc": "valBC"
  }
}
```

I thought of parsing the `Document` object myself but I was wondering if there is an easier/faster way of doing that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"b" element can be extracted and put into a new document this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <rapidjson/document.h>
#include <rapidjson/stringbuffer.h>
#include <rapidjson/writer.h>

using namespace rapidjson;

int main(void)
{
    const char* json = "{\"a\": \"valA\",\"b\": {\"ba\": \"valBA\",\"bb\": \"valBB\",\"bc\": \"valBC\"},\"c\": \"valC\"}";

    Document d;
    d.Parse<0>(json);

    Value& data = d["b"];

    Document d2;
    d2.SetObject();
    d2.AddMember("b", data, d2.GetAllocator());

    rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
    rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
    d2.Accept(writer);

    std::cout << buffer.GetString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
{"b":{"ba":"valBA","bb":"valBB","bc":"valBC"}}
```

Comment: I don't want to just access it. I want to put it in a separate `Document` object.